How do I make AnyConnect connect at first try in a public WLAN that needs a confirmation click in a pop up window? It always needs a second try
With AnyConnect, if I am in an unknown WLAN that needs a confirmation of the rules in a pop up window at first login, I need to double connect to the network to fully load the login site, be it in a restaurant or train or wherever.
The first try loads the pop up for the login but stops before it has been loaded showing "your connection is broken" together with a broken button to refresh, and a click on that broken button does not work, it is just not loaded well enough.
If I log in to a known password protected WLAN that does not need this confirmation, I can enter the internet at once.
How can I avoid having to wait for the second try's pop up window as the fully working login site? It needs a minute or two only to connect again and wait for that pop up window again. I guess Anyconnect tries to protect that first connect in a tunnel, which the pop up window cannot handle. But this is just a guess.
If I leave the network for a standby and need to reconnect, I can open the fully loaded pop up window to log in at "first try", it seems to remember the network then from the time before the logout.
